# Is there a python 2 module named "HTML"?

Tags: python, python-module

A python repository on GitHub is trying to `import HTML` but I can't find any module with this name (in all upper case).

Statement in question: https://github.com/Wi-FiTestSuite/Wi-FiTestSuite-UCC/blob/master/python/myutils.py#L29

The closest one I could find is this module: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html but after installing that the import statement still doesn't work, because of the case mismatch right? So have I overlooked the correct way to resolve this dependency or do I need to raise an issue with the developers?

Comment: The module isn't even being used within that file, so I'm not sure why it can't be commented out/removed for your purposes...

Comment: @Makoto could do, but I don't want to maintain a fork or patches unless it's necessary.

Comment: Well...there's only two ways to go about it, and your options are to either fork it or to submit a bug.  I genuinely don't see it being used, so I don't see an issue with forking it personally...

Comment: @makoto sounds like you know the answer to the question... But I still don't!